# data annotations hide property/field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have a model

```
class Address {
 public int AddressID {get;set;}
 public string Street {get;set;}
 public string City {get;set;}
 public string State {get;set;}
 public int ZipCode {get;set;}
}
```

in my view, when I have

`@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address)` (assuming Address is a complex property inside another model)

I get a label for every one of Address properties, so I get:

AddressID:

Street:

City:

State:

ZipCode:

problem is, I don't want the ID property to show up, I tried these two annotations:

```
[Display(AutoGenerateField = false)]
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
```

but the first one doesn't do anything for some reason, and the HiddenInput keeps getting a red squiggly line, not sure if they both use the same `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` assembly

Answer (score 18, accepted):

just found the answer actually..

`[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]` works but I had to add:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

using Web.Mvc will not work with MVC 6 instead use this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
```

Answer (score 1):

as for me, when I'm used

```
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
```

to my model props I still got displaying in schaffolded Create/Edit views. When I was just removing that code from view - yes, it wasn't visible any more, but after saving edits I got another problem: props for what I remove editors change their values to `null`.
I use this on edit views to fix it

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ImageUrl)
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this supposed to deny scaffolding to show the field on the generated views?

```
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
```