# Data annotation for not autodisplay columns in asp.net web forms gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-annotations

I'm currently working in asp.net web forms 4.5.

I'm using gridview and gridview has a nice feature called autogenerate
columns, and I'm trying to use it but there are some columns I don't want to show.

I know that I can set autogenerate column to false and call the columns for myself, but I was thinking if there is a feature such as data annotation on model, (I'm using database-first, by the way) and prevents the gridview from 
displaying.

The closest post I found is [data annotations hide property/field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162340/data-annotations-hide-property-field) but I don't think this applies to my case.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WebForms there is no simple tagging like in MVC to hide columns with data annotations. If you want to use autogenerate columns you can hide column in a data bound event using index of the column:

```
protected void gridView_DataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
{
    e.Row.Cells[index].Visible = false;
}
```

I would advise not to use auto generated columns, but to explicitly specify each column in the gridview. This way, you don't get any unexpected behavior in your GUI if your data source changes in the future.

Comment: Where would you put this using a WebForms GridView? Because I would not know where to put that.

Comment: I can't use it because HiddenInput uses System.Web.Mvc but I'm using web forms...It doesn't even compile..

Comment: @JinmoChong You are right, I completely missed that. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @zm again, thank you so much. You have no idea how much help this is to me. not only in convenience, but also other stuffs too!

Answer (score 0):

If you've made a model with data annotations and you've given it a name that won't display in your gridview make sure you're setting the ItemType on the Gridview and pointing it towards you model. It will work just fine.